# Esconder h2 si no hay nada en input tipo search

Tags: php, html

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Tengo un buscador con php que me mustra los resultados desde la base de datos y un h2 donde me dise(Resultados de busqueda para:'el texto que ingrese en el buscador')
pero cuando no pongo nada en el buscador que es un input tipo search con un boton con el name="enviar" me sigue apareciendo el mismo h2.

Anteriormente hice un scrip para que no me lo mostrara mientras no se accionara de esta forma:

```
<?php
session_start();

function esconderv3(){
    if(!isset($_GET['enviar'])){
        echo "esconder";
    }
}

function esconderv4(){
    if(isset($_GET['enviar'])){
        echo "esconder";
    }
}
```

?>

Y el html

```
<h2 class="<?php esconderv3(); ?>">Resultados de búsqueda para:</h2><h2 class="<?php esconderv3(); ?>"><?php echo $búsqueda ?></h2>
```

Ahora como podria hacer para que al no ingresar nada en mi buscador se deje de mostrar ese h2??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente así:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['enviar']))
    echo '<h2 class="esconder">Resultados de búsqueda para:</h2>'
        .'<h2 class="esconder">'.$busqueda.'</h2>';
```

O, con un `style="display:none"`, si es que prefieres ocultarlo desde CSS.